# How to properly lock desktop when hibernating?

Tags: arch-linux, awesome, hibernate, xscreensaver

If I [lock the screen](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/3343ac5ea305a7a67186457c30a552144563aaaf/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L324-L330), hibernate by closing the laptop lid, open the laptop lid and press the power button, the screen will just show a black surface and I can start typing the password immediately. If I *don't* lock the screen before hibernating, wait about 30s, open the laptop lid and press the power button, the screen will show the desktop and then fade to black as if `xscreensaver` had been activated *after exiting* hibernation. Only after the fadeout can I deactivate the screensaver. How can I make sure `xscreensaver` is always properly activated when hibernating, so that I won't have to wait for the fadeout?

Comment: I don't use `xscreensaver` anymore, but I remember [its manual](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xscreensaver1.html) has a part called "restart xscreensaver when someone logs in", which suggests doing `xscreensaver-command -exit; xscreensaver &` on login. Maybe you could do that on wake-up to reset its state?

Comment: That sounds like a timing attack waiting to happen.

Comment: This one of those little perks that bug me more than they should.

Answer (score 6):

I recently solved this problem myself on `Arch Linux`.  I used the program `xss-lock` from the `AUR` found [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xss-lock/).

I was trying to set up a service to lock the screen on sleep but for some reason I couldn't get it to work.  I ended up using `xss-lock` and it worked very easily.

1. Install [xss-lock](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xss-lock/) from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/).
2. Add one of the commands below to your `.xprofile` or appropriate startup script for your WM/DM.

My `.xprofile`:

```
xss-lock -- /usr/bin/slock &
```

For `xscreensaver`:

```
xss-lock -- /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -lock &
```

Comment: xss-lock apparently moved to [xss-lock-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xss-lock-git/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for myself by switching to a dedicated screen locker instead of xscreensaver.

I use [xtrlock on Debian](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/xtrlock), but it seems to be unavailable on Arch. [Here's a blog post](http://z-issue.com/wp/screen-lockers-xtrlock-and-slock/) describing some of the alternatives on Arch.

Answer (score 0):

Almost fixed using [`xautolock` with `slock`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/e4c1ac1745c7c2ffdcf52d747a13d500a9022363#diff-e8e122e009dedd906bd1c5c948a40a20) and a simple [screen locking service](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/497da5f7b235674a6a351469aac3b21581b18122). The service currently [only works on the system level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/how-to-run-systemd-user-service-to-trigger-on-sleep-aka-suspend-hibernate), but hopefully someone will be able to help with that.

Edit: [Even though the service clearly says `Before=sleep.target` I still sometimes see the desktop flicker when resuming.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155991/why-does-my-before-sleep-target-service-run-after-resuming)