# Why does my Before=sleep.target service run *after resuming*?

Tags: systemd, suspend, xautolock

I've defined the following [service](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/497da5f7b235674a6a351469aac3b21581b18122) to [start a screen locker before suspending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144591/how-to-properly-lock-desktop-when-hibernating):

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/screenlock.service
[Unit]
Description=Lock X session using slock
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=my_user
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xautolock -locknow

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

It is loaded when booting:

```
$ systemctl status screenlock.service 
● screenlock.service - Lock X session using slock
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/screenlock.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and it is run at some point between triggering suspend to RAM and resuming work:

```
$ systemctl status screenlock.service 
● screenlock.service - Lock X session using slock
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/screenlock.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 17 08:22:22 machine systemd[1]: Starting Lock X session using slock...
Sep 17 08:22:22 machine systemd[1]: Started Lock X session using slock.
```

But **if it's run *before* suspending, why do I see a flicker of the desktop before the screen locker turns on when resuming?** Is `Before` or `sleep.target` not defined as one would expect? Is `xautolock` or [`slock`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/e4c1ac1745c7c2ffdcf52d747a13d500a9022363#diff-e8e122e009dedd906bd1c5c948a40a20) faulty?

(I've verified that there's no other service interfering by disabling this one, suspending, resuming, and getting no screen locker.)

Comment: FWIW, I just start `slock` from the screenlock service (removes another process) and I never see a flicker... `xautolock` just handles locking on timeouts.